# Does PHP have a don't care variable like Haskell?

Tags: php, variables, haskell

On [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions), I read:

> ```
> first :: (a, b, c) -> a  
> first (x, _, _) = x  
> second :: (a, b, c) -> b  
> second (_, y, _) = y  
> third :: (a, b, c) -> c  
> third (_, _, z) = z
> ```
>
> The `_` means the same thing as it does in list comprehensions. It means that we really don't care what that part is, so we just write a `_`.

Is there something like that in PHP as well? If so, what can it be used for? If not, why did the developers choose not to implement it?

Comment: Show your example where you want to use it. And show possibility syntax of it.

Comment: @sectus I'm just wondering - don't know if it would be useful, this is purely hypothetically. A possible syntax could be `$_` or `$`, but that's based on my imagination only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that built in PHP. And there hasn't been much need for anything similar, since PHP's functional features are now (with the advent of PHP 5.5) only just starting to grow out of childhood. For the time being you don't see functions that accept callbacks a whole lot and in addition the lambda syntax is somewhat verbose, so a feature that allows you to more conveniently declare lambdas is not very high on the usefulness ladder.

In Haskell `_` is a shorthand way to say "there's a parameter here but I don't care about it", and each appearance of `_` is considered to be a *different* parameter from each other appearance.

A quirk of PHP that allows you to simulate this syntax is the fact that a function can have multiple parameters with the same name:

```
// compiles with no problem!
function foo($param, $param, $param) {
    echo $param;
}

foo(1, 2, 3); // prints 3
```

It follows that you can do this if you wish to ignore the first two parameters of the function:

```
function foo($_, $_, $param) {}
```

However, this means nothing special to the compiler and is no different than using distinct names for the parameters. It's not idiomatic PHP and would most likely confuse readers of this code. So while you can do it, IMHO it's not a good idea.

As an aside, there is one place in PHP where you are allowed to definitely declare that you don't care about pieces of information: the `list` construct.

```
$a = array(1, 2);
list($x, $y) = $a; // assigns $x = 1 and $y = 2
```

You can skip as many arguments as you want in `list`, for example:

```
list(, $y) = $a; // assigns $y = 2, the first element is ignored
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean an optional argument in a function? You can achieve this like this:

```
function add($x = 1, $y = 1) {
  return $x + $y;
}

add(4,5); //9
add(3); //4
```

Note: you cannot provide just the second argument and not the first one, something like this

```
add(_,4) //error!
```

does not exist.